# Backup and restore LXC container with LAMP stack - MySQL cannot start in container

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, lxc

I've followed these simple instructions in order to backup and restore an LXC container:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194341

The backup and restore procedure go well. I've made triple sure I use the --numeric-owner flag when tar and untar'ing, and the container starts up fine. However, MySQL in the container barfs all over the place with the following errors, when doing **service mysql restart** (output from journalctl -xe):

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

and

```
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

I can get it to start up if I delete the following files, so that mysql recreates them:

/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1

/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*

/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control

"Solution" gleaned from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160277

But this royally messes up my site database.

**What is going on here?**

It seems to me that file permissions, or something along those lines have gone awry - but when I compare ownership and rights between the original, working container and my restored copy, it all looks identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might bump into this: Typical n00b error on my part.

I had forgotten to update the rootfs path in my config file for the container.

As I was doing a restore test of an existing container, I had untar'ed my backup to another directory in /var/lib/lxc - e.g. /var/lib/lxc/restored - but hadn't updated the config in /var/lib/lxc/restored/config to point to the correct path.

This resulted in the container using the same rootfs as my original - still running - container. This the problems with Mysql.

Interesting to note that you can spin up two containers sharing the same rootfs. Maybe there's some applications for this "feature" somewhere.

LXC is awesome.